# return both result from elasticsearch does it possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, updates

I have a rails app and per user create indexes, each index contains documents and each document contains a user profile, profile_id is unique per user, In my case user could update his profile and in my system, I created indexes assume today user-created profile with the first name "rose" and next day decide to update his profile and last name to his profile I need to return both documents when user search, In another word I need if the user wants to search first name elastic return all documents that contain user profiles.
Does anyone know what is query in elastic search?

Comment: why you are creating multipul document for same user profile ? insted of it, you can update existing document with lastname when user update it. it will be very easy to get document and you will get everything in single document. You can use `upsert` when you are index document.

Comment: because admin require to check history of user action in my app, and i could not update each time because in this app at least i have more than 1 million index document  so it's impossible to update indexes.

Comment: I am not agree on point `1 million index document so it's impossible to update indexes.` because elastic can handle this scenario very easily. As per my understanding you are mixing 2 things, one is user details and second is user activity. User activity should be track as logs and index to elastic seperatly so admin can access easily that details. Can you please add sample query if you have tried and sample document for above scenario.